# Aurelia custom binding with Parent resolver not injecting correct container

Tags: aurelia

Using a Parent.of resolver on a custom binding behavior does not work.

The DI container received by the resolver is the root container. This stops it from finding the correct parent to inject.
Using a custom attribute with the same Parent.of decoration works as expected.

An HTML snippet:

```
<form cs-validate-context="login">

    <div class="ui two column grid">


        <label class="column" t="branchcode"></label>
        <div class="form-group ui input column">
            <input type="text" t="[placeholder]branchcode" value.bind="branchcode & csValid" cs-valid="x">
        </div>
```

The **cs-validate-context** gets injected correctly with Parent.of resolver into the attribute, **cs-valid**, but not the custom binding, **csValid**.

Is this expected or is it a matter of RT*M ?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is because a binding doesn't actually 'belong' to any component. In recent debugging an issue on the i18n plugin it seems like an optimisation in the binding system caches identical bindings, this can be across multiple views, so for this to be the case I'd say that a binding doesn't know about its owning 'scope' and can't resolve the parent container.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your custom binding behaviour do?

Comment: @Charleh My custom binding has the validate context injected. The binding should then register itself with the context. So I can then reuse the same widget in a different context using different validation with not changes. I got this working with custom elements, which is a lot simpler to work with. This way my controller does not know about any validations.

Comment: I'd stick that as an answer on your question then, for future Aurelia head-scratchers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aurelia attribute do get the correct parent injected.

So I used it instead of the aurelia binding.